# Append string formated html element to an element adds double quotations around the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically generating a string which contains the code of HTML form element. Then I want to set this element as a child element to an existing node. Following is my code.

```
$('#parentNode')[0].append(render(content))
```

And it's output is following - You can see appended double-quotation marks

```
<html>
  <div id='MatchMakingResults'>
    "<form>Dynamic child node</form>"
  </div>
</html>
```

I tried `$('#parentNode')[0]append($.parseHTML(render(content));`

But then it encodes the string as an object. How can I remove these double-quotation marks from the added element?

Comment: maybe those quotes marks are in your string....

Comment: Why are you using the [`.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) method of the DOM node instead of jQuerys [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)?

Comment: What is happening inside your `render()` function?  I'm wondering if that's what's adding the quotation marks. Alternatively, what does the `content` variable actually contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answer from [@OriDrori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157454/ori-drori) (which should clear up your confusion), you can also just set the `innerHTML` property instead so you do not have to parse the string (this would make more sense if you were to jettison the jquery and just use vanilla js). For example:

```js
const childNode = '<form>Dynamic child node</form>';
$('#parentNode')[0].innerHTML = childNode;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentNode"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use jQuery's [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of the native DOM [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append). The jQuery's method can convert a complicate string to HTML.

To do so, remove the `[0]` from the call, because it refers to the DOM node, and then you use the native DOM append.

```js
var content = '<form>Dynamic child node</form>';

$('#MatchMakingResults').append(render(content));

function render(content) {
  return content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MatchMakingResults"></div>
```

Using the native DOM append, you can see it added as a string:

```js
var content = '<form>Dynamic child node</form>';

$('#MatchMakingResults')[0].append(render(content));

function render(content) {
  return content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MatchMakingResults"></div>
```

Comment: The native `append()` function doesn't add the extra quotation marks they're asking about, does it?  (Your code sample gives identical results using either jQuery's append or the native one.)

Comment: @DanielBeck - it actually renders it as a string (see the example I've added). I'm not sure about the quotation marks.